# Compare Data Between 2 Tables Of Oracle In Most Optimised Way In Java

Tags: java, oracle, performance

I have 2 tables in Oracle database. 
I want to compare these tables in the most optimum way. 
Below is an example of what I would want to accomplish.

Table 1

```
ID    FieldA   FieldB              
1      X         Y
2      C         D
3      E         F
4      G         H       
5      I         J
```

Table 2

```
ID    FieldA   FieldB 
10     Z          V
8      K          L
1      O          P
2      S          T
```

These 2 tables must be compared based on the ID.
If an ID is not existing in Table2, I would want to insert that information in Table2.
If an ID is existing in Table2, I would want to update the information in Table2 by overwriting the information present in Table1.
Also, I need to identify ID's that are present in Table2 but missing from Table1 and mark a column in Table 2 so that it indicates a missing entry.

Both the tables are identical in their structure (Number of columns,the column names, the indexes).

My idea is to do the following:

- For each record in table 2, find its existence in table 1 (this could be done by writing a query)
  If the record with this ID does not exist in table 1, mark this record with a flag to indicate its invalid entry. 
  If the record with this ID exists in table 1, overwrite the entry in table 2 with entry in table 1. Also, maintain this ID information in some data structure.
  After iterating through all the records in table 2,
  write a query that will fetch records from table 1 such that the ID maintained in the above mentioned data structure is not part of Table 1.
  Insert these records into Table 2 now.

End result should be like this:

Table 2

```
ID FieldA   FieldB
10   Z         V  ---> This row will be marked with a flag to indicate its an invalid entry
8    K         L  ---> This row will be marked with a flag to indicate its an invalid entry
1    X         Y
2    C         D
3    E         F
4    G         H
5    I         J
```

There can be millions of records in both the tables.
Can anyone suggest an optimal way of achieving this result for huge amounts of data ? (Any sample code snippet would help).I am not sure if multithreading would help as I have very minimal knowledge on threads.

Note: After each insertion/modification of an entry, I would want to invoke some API's to log some messages.

Answer (score 2):

Don't even think about writing any java for this. Such things should be done in the DB. Learn some SQL.

> If an ID is not existing in Table2, I would want to insert that information in Table2.

I don't know the exact Oracle syntax, but it goes along this lines

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Id WHERE Table2.Id IS NULL)
```

That's all, no data get sent from the DB to the application. How it works:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Id
```

would pair each rows from Table1 with a row from Table2 having the same Id.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Id
```

additionally returns all rows from Table1 having no corresponding row in Table2. For them Table2.Id is NULL.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Id WHERE Table2.Id IS NULL
```

filters out the rows having a non-null Table2.Id, i.e., the matching ones.

The insert inserts... that's all. Databases are optimized for such tasks, so one million rows is peanuts.

Comment: I am using hibernate technology. Please note I need to flag and raise some events for invalid entries as explained in the example. Also, after insertion of new records into Table 2 or modification of existing records in Table 2, I would need to call some API and show some event messages to the user intimating them about the action that has taken place.

Comment: @RS389 From Hibernate you can obtain a connection, too, and execute the SQL. For setting the flag, use something like `UPDATE T1 LEFT JOIN T2 SET T1.Flag = TRUE WHERE T2.Id IS NULL`. Either read the records missing from the other table before the insertion or add a corresponding flag when records get inserted and read them afterwards. This part needs the data transfer to the client, so it makes sense to use Hibernate directly; all the other parts are much simpler and faster in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

> If the record with this ID exists in table 1, overwrite the entry in table 2 with entry in table 1. Also, maintain this ID information in some data structure.

I would use `MERGE` statement. It would take care of the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` logic. You have two tables, you need to check the IDs in table_1, so your `USING` clause will have `SELECT column_list... FROM TABLE_1`

The logic would be :

`WHEN MATCHED THEN INSERT....`

and

`WHEN NOT MATCHED`
`THEN`
`UPDATE TABLE_2...`

So, all you are doing is `MERGE INTO TABLE_2`

Read the documentation about MERGE here http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm

You can find more examples about the MERGE statement here http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/merge-enhancements-10g.php

Comment: Please not that I do have other fields in my table and not all of it should get updated when there are differences between the tables. Only FieldA and FieldB must be modified.

Comment: So what? `update table set field_A = new_val_A, field_B = new_val_B;` You can also add a `WHERE` clause. I think this is the solution that you need and should implement.

Comment: I need to invoke some Java apis after insertion/updation of each record.

Comment: Each record? You mean row by row? Can't it be in `BULK`? ***row by row is slow by slow***

Comment: Yes, after each record I need to do that. That is my requirement. I was wondering whether I can create a ThreadPool and use the approach I had thought of and distribute data to each of the threads but I am not sure if there are better approaches than this. Please suggest.

Comment: I don't know about java requirement, but is it possible to write a `Trigger for each row` for your requirement? Or, from Java is there a way to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would want to do it from Java and I have specified my approach above. It's just that I want to optimize it so that performance does not get impacted when there is huge amount of data.

Comment: To improve database operation performance, use the `MERGE` statement as explained in my answer.